# difference among もちろん、きっと、必ず、ぜひ

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

もちろん、きっと、必ず、ぜひ。

どうやって区別しますか?　ところで、似たような言葉がありますか。教えてください。よろしくお願いしますm(_ _)m

Comment: 日本語で教えてほしいですか？英語は？

Comment: 文中で副詞として使う場合の話ですか？それともほぼ単独で"Sure!"みたいに使う場合の話？「週末にパーティがあるんですが、ご出席いただけます？」-- 「ええ、｛もちろん・きっと・必ず・ぜひ｝（+ 伺います）！」みたいな・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer does not address the part of the question "似たようなことばがあったら教えてください”

There are a few I can think of for きっと/必ず

いつも is similar to 必ず。

> 頼んだら、彼は(いつも/必ず)やってくれる。
>
> If he is asked to do something, he will always do it

絶対に is like きっと but a little stronger.

> 彼は絶対に誘われたけど、来なかった。
>
> 彼はきっと誘われたけど、来なかった。
>
> He was definitely invited, but didn't come. But 絶対に is more certain.

どうぞ is like ぜひ。It's like "yes, go ahead and "

> どうぞ、入ってください！
>
> "Go ahead and come in!"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

**もちろん** - Of course

> A: 日本語、勉強してる？　B: もちろん！
>
> A: Do you study Japanese? B: Of course!

Note: this form of "of course" can come across as rude because it gives off the message of "you should know already."

**きっと** - Certainly/for sure/definitely (with 90% certainty)

> 彼はきっと来るよ。
>
> He'll definitely come.

**必ず** - Definitely/without a doubt/for sure (with 100% percent certainty)

必ず is used the same way as きっと.

**ぜひ** - By all means (goes at the beginning of a sentence or clause)

> ぜひ来てください。
>
> By all means, please come.